# Returning the value of LINQ Query ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my repository class I have this:

```
public xxxxx GetByxxxx(string value)
{
    return context.xxxxx.Where(r => r.value== value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then I am calling it in my controller like this

```
var result = ((xxxxRepo.GetByName(name)));
```

The value of result keeps returning null but name keeps returning the value on the db using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The result is " + result);
```

What am I missing.

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is.  When you step through the code in a debugger, where specifically does it fail?  What are the runtime values which cause this failure?  What have you done to determine that those values shouldn't cause the failure?

Comment: It fails at the point of getting the value of result because I want to pass it to my view model using the breakpoints. Thanks

Comment: If the repository is returning `null`, then the repository is returning `null`.  Which means there's no matching value found by that `Where` clause.  There isn't much we can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are return object. So when you print value to use this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The result is " + result==null?"":result.Name);
```

Comment: It returns a nullreference exception was unhandled by user code using result.Name

Comment: @PatrickNdu try to debug and see if the line return context.xxxxx.Where(r => r.value== value).FirstOrDefault(); even returns anything.

Comment: It is handled null.But you want result then you check data exit to database.

Comment: Thanks at Mukesh. Its been sorted. Please I want to pass the value to the view to use it to perform a search and assign it against html5 video tag. Any ideas.